# HTML5 <section> tag clarification with example

Tags: html

I've read up a lot on the usage of `<article>` and `<section>`. I think I get the `<article>` part. But with `<section>` there is still confusion. I've read [this post](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) on HTML5doctor, but I still have questions.

Consider an easy example: I have a webpage where you can play a game. You have a navigation menu at the top with "Dashboard", "Other games", "About". Each page begins with a headline and contains lower level headlines.

For instance, on Dashboard you could have "Singleplay", "Multiplayer", "Statistics", "Instructions" with a bit of text under each and a link to the respective HTML page.

On html5doctor:

> The section element represents a generic document or application section

I'm guessing each "page" could be considered as such? **But are the sub headlines ALSO sections in this case or not?**. It feels like whenever there is a new headline with content, a `<section>` could be argued suitable. But that can get out of hand, no..?

Comment: "It feels like whenever there is a new headline with content, a <section> could be argued suitable". That's pretty much it. In HTML4 each h1-h6 element *implicitly* starts a new section. The <section> element just provides an *explicit* way to do the same thing. This explicitness is useful when you want to indicate that the section starts before the first h1-h6 element, or when you want to indicate the end of the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<section>` element is used to represent a group of related content. This is similar to the purpose of an `<article>` element with the main difference being that the content within a `<section>` element doesn’t necessarily need to make sense out of the context of the page. A section is just how it sounds a section of a website. I think the most common use is that you can assign it an id. So it is it's own entity so to speak. You can assign it an `<section id="examples">` and have it go to that section of a website from anywhere and the page you want.

It’s advisable to use a heading element (`<h1>` – `<h6>`) to define the topic for the section.

Using this blog post as an example, you could have `<section>` elements that represent each of the individual parts within the post.

```html
<article>
  <h1>How to use HTML5 Sectioning Elements</h1>
  <p>...</p>

  <section>
    <h2>The <main> Element</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>The <article> Element</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>The <section> Element</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>
  ...
</article>
```

Comment: So you'd suggest having sections for each of the headlines? How far would this stretch though? The definition "group of related content" doesn't tell me much. What kind of content? Headlines? Text? The text under a headline is always related, so that tells me that headlines should always be used with a <section> tag.

Comment: About Us,
Contact Us,
What’s New, 
Events,
Testimonials,
Frequently Asked Questions, these are just some examples of sections. An article would be like a blog post is the easiest I can describe. It has more information.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example that might help:

```
<html>
    <head>             
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
           <section id='first'>
           </section>
           <section id='second>
           </section>
        <main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Without context it doesn't really do much for me. My professor gave me an example where he has a page that displays "our products", "our services". These are in section tags. For "our products", there are subheadings called "electronics", "food", etc. These are also in section tags. But further "down", he stops using it. I want to know why.